# Swift assert anyway to print variables in string

Tags: swift, assert

**Background:** 
In Objective-C, I would create my assertion with debug information included:

```
NSAssert(poetCount > 5, "Expected poetCount > 5; Actual: %d", poetCount);
```

However, the global `assert` function in Swift doesn't seem to allow this, because the message parameter is a StaticString. So I can NOT do this:

```
assert(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fullpath), 
"Expected: File to Exist @ \(fullpath)")
```

**Question:** Is there an alternative `assert` function that does not require a static string, or should I continue using `NSAssert` if I want to put in extra information to make debugging easier?

Comment: What happens if you replace the "Expected......" part with a string objects? Sorry, on Windows, can't test.

Comment: @LordZsolt If I write `let assertString = "Expect: sectionIndex > 0; Actual \(sectionIndex)"; assert(sectionIndex > 0, assertString)` I get this error: "Could not find an overload for 'assert' that accepts the supplied arguments"

Comment: I don't know when apple changed this but the assert can now handle string interpolation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can currently because of the StaticString param. I tried setting the message string with a let but you can't even put a variable in there it seems. It has to be a StaticString in quotes.

For what it's worth, Apple's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister-Swift/Listings/ListerOSX_ListViewController_swift.html) follows the same pattern:

```
assert(listItems && listItems!.count == 1, "There must be exactly one moved item.")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own version of assert with String. Here is example:

```
func assert(condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ message: String = "") {
    #if DEBUG
        if !condition() {
            println(message);
                abort()
        }
    #endif 
}
```

or with additional debug info:

```
func assert(condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ message: String = "", file: String = __FILE__, line: Int = __LINE__) {
    #if DEBUG
        if !condition() {
            println("assertion failed at \(file):\(line): \(message)");
                abort()
        }
    #endif
}
```